# Get Information, Display it in a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

SharePoint 2013 onprem

I am trying to gather information (on a weekly basis) and then display it in a page.

Longer explanation - Users are part of a briefing and before the meeting that need to input their information for the week. Think of something similar to passing around a PowerPoint presentation where everyone updates 'their' slide.

Once they put the information in, the person in charge should be able to navigate to a page to display all the inputted information.

Just need ideas or how anyone else with similar needs may have accomplished this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [simple dashboard](https://www.itunity.com/article/overview-sharepoint-list-styles-406) using 'Box Style' list views, one list for each part of the briefing.  Create a view for each list, in the Style section of the Create View page, select the 'Box style'.  Limit the results to 1 and set the view to show only the latest entry by sorting the view by created (or modified).

Add each of the views to your Briefing page.

Then each person can add a new list item for the latest briefing.